# cURL not loading for Ubuntu 16.04.3 with PHP 5.6

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl

I have a  Ubuntu 16.04.3 server that when I use phpinfo() I find that the server is using PHP Version 5.6.11 on Apache/2.4.18.

I installed curl and when I run `sudo find / -name curl.so\*` I get returned

`/usr/lib/php/20151012/curl.so`

phpinfo() shows the following additional .ini file: /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/99-curl.ini

The contents of this file are `extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/curl.so`

When I run the following on a php page:

```
var_dump(function_exists('curl_init')); print
```

I get `bool(false)`

This occurs even after a `sudo service apache2 restart`

How do I get CURL to run in my PHP pages?

Comment: Did you enable curl in your `php.ini` ?

Comment: I thought that is what the 99-curl.ini was for @Derek?

Comment: Have you tried it with just `extension=curl.so`

Comment: Yes, that is what I had prior.  I changed to this thinking it was a path issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the reason it is not loading is because the API version `20151012` is for PHP 7.0 and not 5.6, so that curl extension module is not compatible with 5.6.

If you do `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` you should get the right extension which should get installed to `/usr/lib/php/20131226`.

The Apache error log should have a startup error saying that the module is not compatible and might offer more detail as to why it's not being loaded.

Comment: I see the directory /usr/lib/php/20131226 and it contains curl.so ...I updated the 99-curl.ini with this value, restarted the web server and it still does not work?  What am I missing?

Comment: You shouldn't need the full path.  What is the value of `extension_dir` show in your phpinfo() output?  Did any warnings appear in the error_log when restarting Apache about why it's failing to load the module?

Comment: extension_dir /usr/lib/php5/20131226

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/curl.so' - /usr/lib/php/20
131226/curl.so: undefined symbol: zend_unset_property in Unknown on line 0